# How to remove values of some particular keys in NSUserdefaults?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to remove particular values from particular keys in user defaults. I have tried many solutions from stack over flow but failed. The code that I have written is

```
NSMutableArray *arr_social_placeholders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"facebook", @"twitter", @"linkedin", nil];
pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[pref removeObjectForKey:[arr_social_placeholders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

While doing this I'm getting exception and finally terminated with message

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9

how to over come it?

Comment: What's the exception you're getting?

Comment: Are you trying to remove the value inside the tableView delegate? If in that case, Are you init the value inside the tableView Delegate (arr_social_placeholders) obvioulsy it will create problem. can you please post the tableVIew Delegate code.

Comment: i think `signal 9` is due to memory issues

Comment: @balagurubaran which delegate method are you asking for. is it cell for row at indexpath or anything

Comment: @CharlesSrstka . Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9

Comment: @LalKrishna How it can be fixed

Comment: How about running without these line of codes? Do you have crash  after commenting ?

Comment: No. when Im trying to remove some values from User defaults only the app is crashing